# Expanding Twitter t.co links

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to create a twitter bot that involves me taking a youtube video link from a tweet. Posted links turn into a specialized link `https://t.co/...`

Can I turn this link back to it's original YouTube link?

I'm using the Python module `tweepy`

Comment: Post the full twitter link here.

Comment: The t.co links are a safety feature of Twitter allowing them to deactivate a link if it is found to be malicious later. In general these links work with a kind of redirect. Use your browsers debugger to see what happens exactly.

Comment: twitter links will open to a blank website which redirects you immediately to the target website by using a javascript.

Comment: @RedowanDelowar I think StackOverflow. doesnt allow posting of shortened links.

Answer (score 2):

twitter links will open to a blank website which redirects you immediately to the target website by using a javascript.

so we can simply make a **GET** request to the url, and extract the url with help of some regex

#### Python method

```py
    import requests
    import re

    def get_original_twitter_url(twitter_url):
        # without masking it as a browser request, it wont work properly
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
        r = requests.get(url = twitter_url,headers=headers)
        data = r.text
        url = re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)\"", data).group("url")
        return url



    print(get_original_twitter_url(<pass twitter url here>))
```

Comment: This is a general solution but he is already working with the Twitter API and the Twitter API does contain information about the expanded URL.

Comment: @TinNguyen, TIL. TBH, I didn't notice the **tweepy** tag in the question. I thought this was a general python probelm. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Twitter Status JSON example with a link: https://pastebin.com/PZCE9v2c
Twitter Status: https://twitter.com/redditdota2/status/1237997630216712193

When extracting the text you get:

```
"text":"Everyone 2-0 @Cloud9 at @DOTA2 Summit 12 https://t.co/...#dota2 https://t.co/..."
```

The `text` contains `t.co` links. However in the json object you can retrieve the `display_url` and the `expanded_url`.

```
"urls":[
  {
    "display_url":"redd.it/fh7i27",
    "expanded_url":"https://redd.it/fh7i27",
    "indices":[
      41,
      64
    ],
    "url":"https://t.co/..."
  }
]
```

With this you can easily adjust your `text` with the correct URLs.

```
for url in urls:
  text.replace(url['url'], url['expanded_url'])
```

There is a similar project here: https://github.com/nntin/discord-twitter-bot

PS: I removed the full t.co links because StackOverflow wouldn't allow me to post my answer otherwise.